# Creating Automated Installer for Oracle DB+WLS and DB2+WS

Tags: oracle, automation, installation

I am looking for a way to automate a silent installation of 2 tech-stacks on windows/linux, where the user can choose the tech stack and the platform.

```
1. Oracle Stack: Database + Weblogic (Windows / Linux)
2. IBM Stack: DB2 + Websphere (Windows / Linux)
```

I could silent install them individually using response files.

How can this be automated by creating an installer tool to package all these together where the user can choose either of the stacks and the platform for the silent installation of both a components.

Not asking for the entire process, but some direction on how to proceed and which tool to use will be great.

Answer (score 2):

We're using Chef to do full deployments with Weblogic and Oracle, both Windows and Linux.

Check it out here: http://www.opscode.com/chef/

Chef uses "cookbooks" and "recipes" which are sets of instructions written in Ruby to automate deployment in a repeatable way.

If you're interested you can google around for Oracle and Weblogic cookbooks other people have created, there are plenty of examples.

Oracle cookbook: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/oracle

There are also lots of video tutorials like this series: http://nathenharvey.com/blog/2012/12/06/learning-chef-part-1/

All of that said, it will take a while to learn, even though you don't need to know very much Ruby. So if you are looking for something with a really quick turn around you might be better off writing your own scripts or maybe someone else will post an idea.